# Tkinter. Вернуться в начало

Tags: python, tkinter

Не знаю как из функции 'to_be' вернуться в назад, выйти из функции.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

try:
    # python2
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    # python3
    from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('MyGui')
root.geometry('600x600')

def clear():
    # очистить фрейм от виджетов
    if frm.winfo_children():
        frm.winfo_children()[0].destroy()

def to_be(event):
    clear()
    lab = Label(frm, text='What time is it?')
    clear()
    lab.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
    but = Button(frm, text='home')
    but.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.7, anchor='center')
    # здесь мне нужно вернуться в начало программы
    but.bind('<Button-1>', 'по нажатию кнопки нужно выйти из функции')

frm = Frame(root, width=500, height=500, bg='#008B8B')
lab = Label(frm, text='Глагол to be', bg='#008B8B',
    font='Inconsolata 13')

lab.place(x=250, y=10,  anchor='center')
but = Button(frm, text='Ok', bg='blue')
but.place(x=200, y=20, width=100)
frm.pack()
but.bind('<Button-1>', to_be)
root.focus_force()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Программа и так выходит из функции `to_be()` после выполнения `but.bind(...)`. Напишите, что именно вы хотите сделать, что значит "вернуться назад"?

Comment: Мне нужно вернуться на начало там где присутствует надпись 'Глагол to_be'.

Comment: Похоже, вам нужно просто вынести код, выполнение которого вам нужно "повторить", в отдельную функцию, и ее привязать к нажатию на кнопку.

Comment: Ага! я так и думал. Спасибо Вам!

Comment: если получилось, оформите в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Решил сам, бред полный, но работает. Оформил главную функцию 'basic'(в моем случае это главное окно моей программы. Привожу код!

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

try:
    # python2
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    # python3
    from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Trainer')
root.geometry('600x600')

def clear():
    if frm.winfo_children():
        frm.winfo_children()[0].destroy()

def to_be(event):
    clear()
    lab = Label(frm, text='What time is it?')
    lab.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
    clear()
    but = Button(frm, text='home')
    but.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.7, anchor='center')
    but.bind('<Button-1>', basic)

frm = Frame(root, width=500, height=500, bg='#008B8B')

def basic(*event):
    clear()
    clear()
    lab = Label(frm, text='Глагол to be', bg='#008B8B',
            font='Inconsolata 13')
    lab.place(x=250, y=10,  anchor='center')

but = Button(frm, text='Ok', bg='blue')
but.place(x=200, y=20, width=100)
frm.pack()
but.bind('<Button-1>', to_be)
root.focus_force()

root.mainloop()

basic()
```

Comment: def to_be(event):                                                                                                                                                             
    return